# WARNING: CSS Error parsing

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am trying to create a GUI in JavaFx. My problem is that I am receiving warning with my CSS style. In fact my warnings are:

> WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-fx-font: 90 Langdon; -fx-base: #AE3522; -fx-text-fill: white; bold;}: 
>   WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-fx-font: 60 Langdon; -fx-text-fill: white; bold; -fx-base: #AE3522 bold;}:

This CSS is assignig to my buttons and Labels:

```
learnin = new Label(" Puzzle ");
learnin.setStyle("-fx-font: 90 Langdon; -fx-base: #AE3522; -fx-text-fill: white; bold;");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this ...

```
learnin.setStyle("-fx-font: 90 Langdon; "
                + "-fx-base: #AE3522; "
                + "-fx-text-fill: white; "
                + "-fx-font-weight:bold;");
```

... or shorter ...

```
learnin.setStyle("-fx-font: normal bold 90 Langdon; "
                + "-fx-base: #AE3522; "
                + "-fx-text-fill: white;");
```

**This part is invalid:** `-fx-text-fill: white; bold;`

You can check the [JavaFX CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typefont) to check how you can style fonts.